# Jenkins: How to mark build as unstable if clang analyzer found new bug

Tags: ios, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, clang-static-analyzer

I have set up Jenkins CI on a mac server to do automated builds/analysis for iOS projects using the Xcode Build and the Clang Scan-Build plugins. I have email notifications set up to notify users if they broke a build using the Editable Email Notification plugin. However, I would also like to email users if the Clang Scan-Build phase detects a new bug since the last commit, which leads to my questions: **How would I have the clang plugin mark a build as unstable/failed if a new bug has been introduced?** (I want to notify users if a new bug has been introduced since the last commit, not just if a threshold has been exceeded.)

I am pretty sure this is possible because the clang plugin already provides a graph of the clang bug count results from previous builds.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but I use the Compiler Warnings plugin to trend my CLANG-LLVM compiler warnings.   This has to be defined at the Jenkins system level (still GUI, but not per-project):

```
Name: CLANG-LLVM
Link Name: Compiler Warnings
Trend Report Name: Warning trend
Regular Expression: ^(.+?):(\d+):(?:\d+:)?(?:\{\d:-\}+)?(?:.*) (warning|error): (.*)$
Mapping Script:
    import hudson.plugins.warnings.parser.Warning
    String fileName = matcher.group(1)
    String lineNumber = matcher.group(2)
    String category = matcher.group(3)
    String message = matcher.group(4)
    if (message.contains('deprecated')) category='deprecation';

    return new Warning(fileName, Integer.parseInt(lineNumber), "Clang-LLVM", category, message);

Example Log Message:
    /Development/foo.m:4634:7: warning: 'runModalForDirectory:file:' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations,6]
```

We then run that in a post-build scan of the console logs.
And, in the `Advanced...` section for the warnings, you can tell it how to interpret them for the "health warning" and status settings.

Comment: Thanks! Adding the Compiler Warning plugin allows me to scan for warnings and mark as unstable when new warnings are introduced.